# Adding dynamically Entry() when when specific option is choosed from combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

If the user chooses a specific option, is there a possibility of dynamically create Entry()?

```
ext_choosen = ttk.Combobox(canvas,width = 27)
point= ['All files']
ext_choosen['values'] = ('By name', 'Enumerate', 'By name and Enumerate')

ext_choosen.grid(column=1, row=3)
ext_choosen.current()
```

In the above example, I'd like to add Entry() in the same window below combobox if user choice is By name or By name and Enumerate.

Comment: Yes, of course. You can create entries in functions, and you can call functions when the combobox value changes.

Comment: @BryanOakley after your comment I've made some research and I think that's it's binding the combobox and callback function to solve my problem is it?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, that's. You helped me a lot thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Bryan Oaklay who gave me a hints I came to solution.
The Combobox needs to be bind and then calls a function which gets the value of combobox.

```
def callbackFunc(n):
    print(ext_choosen.get())

ext_choosen = ttk.Combobox(canvas,width = 27)
ext_choosen['values'] = ('By name', 'Enumerate', 'By name and Enumerate')

ext_choosen.grid(column=1, row=3)
ext_choosen.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackFunc)
```